# Able to adjust a Function/Formula with Weighted Variables to correct for changes in a variable?

Tags: arithmetic, education, functional-equations

I apologize for the somewhat cryptic title as I don't quite know how to word it.

I have a somewhat abstract question that may have a simple answer. But I am wracking my mind all over this!

So assume I have three variables X, Y, and Z

So say I have variable Z which is the number X divided by the sum of X and Y, something mathematically written as Z = X / (X + Y), so X and Y are weighted in determining Z.

Is there a way I can keep this relationship but remove the effects of the Y variable?

So for example, say X = 2, Y = 2, so Z = 2/(2+2) = 2 in on instance

In the second instance X = 2, but Y = 4 so Z = 2/(2+4) = 4 so the value of Z naturally changes because Y is a larger number. Is there a way I could add/adjust this formula so that even though Y is a larger number (in this case 4), I can make Z = 2 again?

Practically speaking, I want to determine how to adjust a equation for changes in one of it's variables to remove the effect of a change in the value (but still maintain the weighting).

Is this even possible? I have to admit my knowledge of mathematics is slight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, don't forget your order of operations! 
$\ x=2 $ and $\ y=2 $ gives the equation 
$$z = 2 / (2 + 2)
$$
$$z = 2 / 4
$$
$$z = 1 / 2
$$

In general, fix $\ z $ to be some constant number $\ c $. $\ c $ can be any number you like: 2, -13, 965, etc.

$$ z = c
$$

Then because $\ z = x / (x + y) $, it is easy to rearrange the variables to have it in the form y = (some function of x)

$$ c = x / (x+y)
$$
$$ c(x+y) = x
$$
$$ cx + cy = x 
$$
$$
cy = x - cx
$$
$$ y = (x- cx) / c
$$
$$ y = (x/c) - x
$$

So in the case of $\ z = 2 $, 
$$ y = (x/2) - x = -(x/2) $$
where x is any real number.For example, let x = 5. then y= -(5/2) gives the equation 
$$z = 5 / (5 -(5/2))  
$$
$$z = 5 / ((10/2) - (5/2))
$$
$$ z = 5 / (5/2)
$$
$$ z = 2 $$

Hope that helps.

Comment: Aw I feel so silly I should've proof read at the very least my problem examples, in any case thank you for that thorough solution and almost intuitive approach, I suppose I could've backed into the z variable that have me that solution! Thank you for your patience and your help!